# React-Redux state of changed value is not refrected on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The state of the App is comprised of 2 independent states managed by: `modelA`, `modelB` reducers. Ignore `modelB`. For `modelA` i have an action - `setInput`. This action is used in the `onChange` listener of component `Whatever` to set `inputVal` val to whatever.

`Whatever` listener should also display the `inputVal`, but that doesn't happen. The changes to `inputVal` are not reflected.

Debugging shows that the state is indeed modified - whatever is entered in the `input` element of `Whatever`, is being save in the state. It's just that the `stateToProps` mapper is not invoked again.

What am i doing wrong?

```
var INPUT = 'INPUT';
var setInput = (val = '') => ({
    type: INPUT,
    payload: val
})

var modelA = (state = {test1: '', test2: false, inputVal: ''}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case this.INPUT:
            state.inputVal = action.payload;
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}
var modelB = (state = {test1: '', content: ''}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state
    }
}

var stateToProps = state => {
    return {
        storeValue: state.modelA.inputVal
    }
}
var dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setStoreVal: (val) => {
            dispatch(setInput(val))
        }
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({modelA, modelB}));
    }
    render() {
        return e(
            ReactRedux.Provider, {store:this.store},
                e('div', null, "App", 
                    e(ReactRedux.connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Whatever), null)
                )
            );
    }
}
class Whatever extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {val:0}
        this.listener = this.listener.bind(this);
    }
    listener(evt) {
        this.props.setStoreVal(evt.currentTarget.value);
        this.setState({val:evt.currentTarget.value});
    }

    render() {
        return e(
            'div', null,
            e('p', null, this.props.storeValue),
            e('input', {onChange:this.listener, val:this.state.val})
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your state is being mutated when you do `state.inputVal = action.payload` . try doing { ...state, inputVal = action.payload } .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Redux assumes that you never mutate the objects it gives to you in the
>   reducer. Every single time, you must return the new state object. Even
>   if you don't use a library like Immutable, you need to completely
>   avoid mutation.

[Never mutate reducer arguments](https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

```
var modelA = (state = {test1: '', test2: false, inputVal: ''}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case this.INPUT:
            return {...state, inputVal: action.payload}; // return new one
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```